# win10 vm crashes Debian host on install

Tags: windows, debian, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, qemu

using qemu kvm virtual machine manager gui

HOST: current debian bulleye

VMs that work:

Any linux distro tried, WinXP, but lags a little.

Windows 10 boots to spinning windows logo, Install begins.

As installation drop down boxes are selected mouse begins to lag leaving ghost trail behind pointer, typing lags and Virt-manager crashes.

Move mouse to host, Alt+Tab and the debian host crashes.  Never experienced vm breaking out of virtual to effect and crash the host machine, why does that happen, anyone?

Is there a guide or tutorial how to correctly install win10 on a linux qemu host.  Maybe in virtual machine manager ?

xml file: https://pastebin.com/pngjjjNZ

Setup  ssh connection for virt-manager and it connects

```
emu+ssh://root@192.168.122.1/system
```

Some suggest a solution to lag problem is ssh into virt-manager, but i can not figure out how to ssh in from local host.  Is it possible to vnc or ssh into virtual machine manager from local host - BEFORE A VM IS STARTED?

Imagining:

ssh -X 192.168.122.78

but still reading if that is possible

Comment: Are you really trying to use virt-manager inside one of your VMs? Why not do it from your workstation?

Comment: debian workstation (Host) with virtual machine manager gui running.  Win10 vm not working - lag and crash

Comment: Your workstation is also the VM host? Then why do you have virt-manager using ssh to connect to libvirtd? It could just connect locally, like it did out of the box.

Comment: using virt-manager natively - locally - on desktop, causes the full system crash.  a youtube showed same lag problem i experience before system failure.  they yourtuber showed vnc into unraid virt-manager - trying to replicate vnc or ssh with -X display to see if that prevents system failure.

Comment: Hm. Sounds like you have hardware issues.

Comment: closing this question - after trying on another system to rule out hardware failure - found same issue occurred installing virt-manager.  Opening new question with more details

Comment: What does "closing this question" mean? It doesn't look closed and you haven't deleted it.